# How do i select the nearest <input>?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, selector

I have an icon 'inside' of an input field.
When I hover, I want the icon to change and the "type" of the input field where it is inside of (I have 3 fields like this, so I want to select this specific one)

HTML:

```
<div class="change_subtitle">Enter Password</div>
<input id="pw_old" class="change_input" type="text"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></input>
<div class="change_subtitle">Enter new Password</div>
<input id="pw_new1" class="change_input" type="password"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></input>
<div class="change_subtitle">Confirm new Password</div>
<input id="pw_new2" class="change_input" type="password"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></input>
<div class="button_confirm" onclick="inputIsValid()">Confirm</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".fa-eye-slash").hover(function(){
                    if($(this).hasClass('fa-eye-slash')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
                        $(this).addClass('fa-eye');
                        $(this).attr('type' = 'text'); // I want to select the input here and change the type of it
                    } else if($(this).hasClass('fa-eye')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('fa-eye');
                        $(this).addClass('fa-eye-slash');
                        $(this).attr('type' = 'password'); // I want to select the input here and change the type of it back
                    }
                })
```

CSS (just to understand what is ment by "inside"):

```
.fa-eye-slash{
    color: #34495e;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.fa-eye{
    color: #34495e;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

So when I hover the icon it should change and change the type of my input field from `"password"` to `"text"` and back later on.

Comment: Don't randomly put `terms` in `code` style `when` they `aren't` code, it impairs readability.

Comment: Maybe the .closest() method of jQuery could help? https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle path https://jsfiddle.net/afckhbpo/

Problem is with

```
$(this).attr('type' = 'text')
```

Use like this:

```
$(this).prev().attr('type', 'text')
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the question in your title, since these icons are `i` elements that immediately follow the field they relate to, `$(this).prev()` will give you a jQuery object for the `input`.

> So when I hover the icon it should change and change the type of my input field from "password" to "text" and back later on.

Once an `input` is created and has a type, you can't change that type (the [spec allows it](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type) but some browsers don't handle it [yet]). Instead, you can have two inputs (one `type="text"`, the other `type="password"`), and show/hide them as appropriate.